# How to merge completion candidates for vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I often rely on `omni-completion` to edit source codes, so my current `.vimrc` contains following setting to gain quick access to intended candidates:

```
inoremap <C-f> <C-x><C-o>
```

Now I find there are many kinds of `ins-completion`s except for `omni-completion` and become interested to use both `tags` and `file names` completions too.

```
1. Whole lines                                          i_CTRL-X_CTRL-L
2. keywords in the current file                         i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N
3. keywords in 'dictionary'                             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K
4. keywords in 'thesaurus', thesaurus-style             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-T
5. keywords in the current and included files           i_CTRL-X_CTRL-I
6. tags                                                 i_CTRL-X_CTRL-]
7. file names                                           i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F
8. definitions or macros                                i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D
9. Vim command-line                                     i_CTRL-X_CTRL-V
10. User defined completion                             i_CTRL-X_CTRL-U
11. omni completion                                     i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O
12. Spelling suggestions                                i_CTRL-X_s
13. keywords in 'complete'                              i_CTRL-N*emphasized text*
```

The question is, how can I list up whole candidates from these specific completion sources  on a `ins-complete-menu` with single command, `<C-f>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the default completion (CTRL-N / CTRL-P); its completion sources can be configured via the `'complete'` option. Unfortunately, from your list, only tags (not file names) can be (and is by default) included in there. (But don't you know beforehand that you want file completion? I particularly like the many different completion commands because they narrow down the result list, which for me is far more valuable than not having to think about which completion to invoke.)

If you really want an all-encompassing completion, you'd have to implement that yourself as a user-completion, and you'd have to re-implement all the built-in sources, as there currently is no way to programmatically get them.

Comment: Yeah, I think `'complete'` option is just the right way to tweak this sort of demands too.  Sadly, there is no filepath option.  I found myself editing `~/.ctags` to somehow insert `find` command output into the tag file and changing `iskeyword` etc.  OK, It's too much trouble, I should get rid of my imap setting and settle into it as is.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the plugin [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache). It can acomplish this but the setting may not be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  But the plugin would be overkill to my task.  I know it's really useful for various situations, but I would rather prefer to keep my `.vimrc` simple.  My dotfiles are versiond by git to be shared with each hosts, and Vundle needs `git-submodule` to keep track of updating for these plugins.  Some hosts don't even have connection to the Internet.  But thanks anyway.